# Using air humidifier wick cleaned with home detergent - Any health concerns?

Tags: safety, air-quality, chemicals

I have been using humidifier with rotating wick, and used to clean it with domestos detergent.

This detergent as said by manufacturer contains:

- Non-ionic surfactants <5% - particular type not known[1], at least 2 might be type 3 health hazard
- Anionic surfactant <5% - particular type not known, at least 2 might be type 3 health hazard
- Sodium Hypochlorite <5% - type 2 health hazard

In particular I'm very alarmed by dangers of Surfactant because of recent exposure about PFAS, PFOA, PFOS types. [2][3][4][5]

Is there risk to health from potentially hazard PPM levels that can be expelled to air from humidifier membrane that has been treated with Surfactant type chemicals even after washing it with water ?

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surfactant#Classification

[2] [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfluorooctanesulfoni…mans_and_wildlife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfluorooctanesulfoni%E2%80%A6mans_and_wildlife)

[3] [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Per-_and_polyfluoroalk…onmental_concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Per-_and_polyfluoroalk%E2%80%A6onmental_concerns)

[4] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfluorooctanoic_acid#Health_concerns

[5] [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_events_rel…oalkyl_substances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_events_rel%E2%80%A6oalkyl_substances)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because if _you_ are concerned, then stop using that detergent and pick a different one. This isn't the place to ask about health hazards of different chemicals. Maybe at [chemistry.se] or [biology.se], but it's probably off topic there, too.

Comment: Most health hazards deal with a person exposed to large amounts over a long time.  Usually a minor concern in most household use cases.  Can always change deterrent.

Comment: @FreeMan AFAIK that most detergents use some types of surfactants in addition to soap, so example in question applicable to broad range of products. This SE has relevant tags for this type of question, that's why I post it here instead of Chemistry. I need some safety, engineering, air measurements and chemistry wisdom.

Comment: "environmentally friendly", "organic", "healthy", "clean" cleaning products are a dime a dozen these days. Pick one that meets your needs. If it doesn't clean sufficiently for your needs, either put up with the "not so clean" or switch back to a "potentially dangerous in massive quantities" cleaner.

Comment: Can also google for making your own homemade disinfecting detergents.  You will then know exactly what is in it.